# Benefits of running a Selenium in Visual Studio Unit Test project vs Windows Console project

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have seen different automation professionals use different types of projects for their Selenium WebDriver projects.

One of the project types I have seen is to do the coding in a Console application project where the Console window is open when you Run the test ( using the main VS run button ).

However, I have also seen others create a Unit Test project which contains the [TestMethod], [TestInitialize] methods and is run by right clicking inside the [TestMethod] and running tests.

Can someone that is knowledgeable provide an answer as to which type of project is most ideal and why?

Thanks

Comment: Unit tests will compile down to a library that can be picked up by a CI system. Console applications won't.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arran, I speculated that. My team's goal is to be able to run the tests in an automated fashion after an automated build and deploy using TFS. Do you think Unit test project is the way to go?

Comment: Absolutely. This is the only way you can then leverage things like reporting, code coverage etc. (The only *easy* way at least).

Comment: Right, I am doing the same thing using VS Unit testing but there are some things to consider. e.g. It is not easy to run the tests without VS installed, perhaps NUnit or some other library makes it easier. Also the problem with doing Selenium test in VS Unit is that quite often the tests need to share the data e.g the driver,pages etc and ideally tests should be Independent, while you can still use "ordered test" to force the flow of the pages it seems like shoehorning special type of testing to a framework that is not designed for it, I am still looking for a best framework to do it